# How to work with Strings in ARM?

Tags: c, assembly, arm

This is a homework question. Frankly, I'm not sure how a C program delivers a string parameter to the assembly level.

I have the function

`StringSearchInString( text, searchString);`

and the parameters

`text = "Hallo Alles klar"`

`searchString = "ll"`

I know ARM delivers the parameters into register R0, R1 respectively for text, searchString, but I'm not sure how this works with charactesr. If each character is 8 bits in length, then the register is mercilessly slaughtered by the incoming string.

I have since read that the ARM APCS converts the arguments as words, of which the first 4 bytes are stored in the register and the rest are loaded in reverse order on the stack.

Sooo... what? I'm not understanding this. The string `text` would be stored in R0, the first four bytes, "Hall" are stored in R0, and the rest in reverse order on the stack? Am I understanding that right? How do I call them?

TL;DR:  How do I pass a string argument from a C-Program into assembly and how do I work/load/do stuff with it?

**ANSWER:**

In the remote case that anybody is looking for a solution to this as well, here it is:

As Greg Hewgill has said, strings are passed as a pointer to the string. Therefore, the value in R0 is an address to the string. You therefore use indirect addressing to access the value like so:

```
StringSearchInString( text, searchString ); // calls the ARM function...

//Going into the ARM function...

LDRB R4, [R0], #1 // Load the first value of R0 into R4 and skip 
                  // ahead one character(8 bits)
                  // Note the "B" in LDR. It indicates that you load ONLY 1 byte!
MOV R0, R4        // Move the value of R4 into R0. This destroys the pointer
                  // Stored in R0! Careful!
```

And success! If your string is "hallo Alles klar" like mine, you will have 0x68 loaded into register R0. This is the ASCII value of "h". From this you should be able to start working with strings.

Comment: In your answer section, when you say in the first assembly comment "and skip ahead" -- do you mean post-increment R0? If you want to post-increment R0 - which is typical if you want to traverse the whole string - you'd want something like "LDRB R4, [R0], #1" (increment by 1 since it's a single character).  Also, do you realize in your next instruction you've effectively clobbered (lost) your string pointer when you load R4 into R0?

Comment: Skip ahead was more or less referring to the user doing whatever the hell they want to do after that. But yes, I realize that you have to you #1, and I inserted R4 into R0 because, when I jump out of the Assembly program into C, the answer is stored in the register R0. However, you are correct, it is a rather poor example, I'll change it.

Comment: No problem, I just wanted to make sure there was no confusion.  Have fun w/ the class, when I was in school ARM didn't even exist yet  ;-)

Comment: complex parameters to functions are always passed using pointers (looking at the asm code), no matter the asm used.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The short answer is that in C, strings are passed as a *pointer* to the character data somewhere else. For example, R0 might contain the value `0x01000078`, which would be interpreted as a pointer to the `"Hallo Alles klar"` data in memory, followed by a null character (`00` byte).. This is not unique to ARM.

Comment: Figured that, but how do I work with it? I've tried loading the register, which doesn't make sense. I tried pointing to it with `ADR`. but the compiler complained. So I'm not sure what else to do.

Comment: @SoulBeaver: I'm afraid my ARM assembly is rusty because I worked with it only briefly a few years ago, but generally you would load the pointer into a register and then use an indirect addressing mode to read the actual characters out of memory (one at a time, usually).

Comment: Thank you! With your little insight I was able to figure out what to do. Hopefully the rest should be a breeze! Updated my question and making you my suggested, and so far only, answer.

Answer (score -1):

It's not really storing in "reverse" order it's just that registers store bytes in big endian format while the stack, which is memory, stores the bytes in little endian. Do not mix registers up with memory. As for the actual order of the stack it can either be descending or ascending depending on how you code your push. With ARM you can tailor your stack frame to grow up or grow down.

Comment: Registers do not have endianness